# Enable grafana, kiali and jaeger after istio Installation?

Tags: istio

I have installed ISTIO using Helm . I forgot to enable grafana, kiali and jaeger. How can i enable all these above services after i have installed istio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [howto](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio): from official repository.
 you need to update [values.yaml](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/values.yaml).
 and turn on  grafana,  kiali and jaeger. For example with kiali change:

```
kiali:
    enabled:  false
```

to

```
kiali:
    enabled:  true
```

than rebuild the Helm dependencies:

```
helm dep update install/kubernetes/helm/istio
```

than upgrade your istio inside kubernetes:

```
helm upgrade install/kubernetes/helm/istio
```

that's it, hope it was helpful

Comment: Or use the `--set` flag to change this values in the upgrade command. It's make easier to track the changes from the default configs: `helm upgrade install/kubernetes/helm/istio --set grafana.enabled=true,kiali.enabled=true,tracing.enabled=true`

Comment: you have to include the name now - `helm upgrade istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio --set grafana.enabled=true,kiali.enabled=true,tracing.enabled=true`

Comment: If you don't have Tiller, the use this `helm template --set grafana.enabled=true,kiali.enabled=true,tracing.enabled=true install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system > istio.yaml` and then `kubectl apply -f istio.yaml `

Answer (score 1):

So did you install direct  or created a yaml from the templates ?

I would run the command you used to install but with template function and then add the options for jaeger,Kiali and grafana.